# Python SQL DB string literals and escaping

Tags: python, sql, mysql, string, literals

Anyone know if the MySQLdb will automatically escape string literals for SQL statements?

For instance I am trying to execute the following:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `account_name` = 'Blah'""")
```

Will this escape the account name automatically? Or will it only escape if I do the following?:

```
x = 'Blah'
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `account_name` = %s""", (x))
```

Or will it do it for both? Can anyone clarify this as I can't find any information on it.

Comment: There's no point for notation `(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no escaping in the first example, it is a raw SQL query. It's valid, it'll work, but obviously it only makes sense if you always want to search for account `Blah`.

When you need to get an account from a name in a variable, you will need the parameterised version. However your example may not work as expected as `(x)` *isn't* a tuple, it's just the value `x`. `x` in a tuple sequence would be `(x,)`. To avoid confusion you may prefer to use the list `[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping is only done when you give the query and data to MySQLdb separately.  That's how it knows what to escape.  :-)

**Thus, only your 2nd example will escape:**

```
x = ('Blah',)
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `account_name` = %s""", x)
```

Note how I changed `x` to to tuple.  That is what MySQLdb expects. It sort of makes sense since you may need to pass in multiple variables.  Like:

```
x = ('Blah','Foo23')
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `account_name` = %s OR `account_code` = %s""", x)
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

**Good Luck. :-)**